# Decoding JPEG MCUs in C#

Tags: c#, c, math, jpeg

> **abstract**
>
> In the process of writing an unpacker for a IPK-archive (NDS Homebrew Image Viewer) I got stuck at the point where I had to decode single MCUs. The original Sourcecode indicates the usage of DCT but the reference implementation is all in ARM assembly...

I'm currently writing a rudimentary unpacker for the files utilized by NDS Homebrew "Image Viewer" (http://gamebrew.org/wiki/Image_Viewer).
The original site seems down but I found the source code (including a file format description) inside the archive hosted on gamebrew.

The unpacker is written in C# due to convenience (BinaryReader) and also because there is no need for it to be fast.

I've already managed to extract the thumbnails. Those are stored as deflated (zlib) BGR-Bitmaps.

The full-size images are split up into MCU's (8x8 samples). Each MCU is also stored in deflated form.
As of now I got the decompressed data with what seems like DCTed data. It also looks like they've "multiplexed" the individual channels (is this the 4:1:1?).

In the NDS version the byte data then gets passed together with a quantization-table (array of 64 signed 16bit-integers) into a function which looks like this:

```
void customjpeg_DecodeYUV411(s32 *pQuantizeTable,u8 *pData,u16 *pBuf)
{
  pDCs=(s16*)pData;
  pACs=(s8*)&pDCs[4*4*6];
  
  static __attribute__ ((section (".dtcm"))) DCTELEM _y0[DCTSIZE2],_y1[DCTSIZE2],_y2[DCTSIZE2],_y3[DCTSIZE2],_cb[DCTSIZE2],_cr[DCTSIZE2];
  
  TYUV411toRGB15_Data YUV411toRGB15_Data[4]={
    { NULL, _y0, &_cb[((4*0)*DCTSIZE)+(4*0)], &_cr[((4*0)*DCTSIZE)+(4*0)] },
    { NULL, _y1, &_cb[((4*0)*DCTSIZE)+(4*1)], &_cr[((4*0)*DCTSIZE)+(4*1)] },
    { NULL, _y2, &_cb[((4*1)*DCTSIZE)+(4*0)], &_cr[((4*1)*DCTSIZE)+(4*0)] },
    { NULL, _y3, &_cb[((4*1)*DCTSIZE)+(4*1)], &_cr[((4*1)*DCTSIZE)+(4*1)] },
  };
  
//  PrfStart();
  // 3.759ms
  for(u32 y=0;y<4;y++){
    YUV411toRGB15_Data[0]._pBuf=&pBuf[((8*0)*64)+(8*0)];
    YUV411toRGB15_Data[1]._pBuf=&pBuf[((8*0)*64)+(8*1)];
    YUV411toRGB15_Data[2]._pBuf=&pBuf[((8*1)*64)+(8*0)];
    YUV411toRGB15_Data[3]._pBuf=&pBuf[((8*1)*64)+(8*1)];
    for(u32 x=0;x<4;x++){
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_y0);
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_y1);
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_y2);
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_y3);
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_cb);
      DCT13bit_asm(pQuantizeTable,_cr);
      
      YUV411_13bit_toRGB15_asm(YUV411toRGB15_Data);
      
      YUV411toRGB15_Data[0]._pBuf+=DCTSIZE*2;
      YUV411toRGB15_Data[1]._pBuf+=DCTSIZE*2;
      YUV411toRGB15_Data[2]._pBuf+=DCTSIZE*2;
      YUV411toRGB15_Data[3]._pBuf+=DCTSIZE*2;
    }
    pBuf+=(DCTSIZE*2)*64;
  }
//  PrfEnd(0); ShowLogHalt();
}
```

(taken from: customjpeg.cpp)

1. why are the calls run 4x4 times per mcu?
2. is it pure DCT? because i don't see where the "dequantization" is done and i've seen (afaik) some references to the zigzag-pattern(?) in the assembly..
3. am I missing something?

I've checked with some online resources, but they only seem to focus on the encoding process.
Unfortunately I lack the mathematical background, therefore I haven't grasped on to the full concept of DCT and thus the reversal process isn't as straight forward to me..

I've spent a whole day to get this running by utilizing libraries and C#-DCT implementations but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: I suspect they are doing sampling.

Comment: The 4:1:1 will likely be YUV411 compression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV411_to_RGB888_conversion